# How do you update Adobe Flash Player for Chromium on Linux Mint MATE 32bit?

Tags: linux-mint, adobe-flash, chromium-os

I'm trying to update Adobe Flash Player for Chromium, but I'm stuck.

Also, I DID have it, but I don't know how to work it.

Can you give me advise, I'd really appreciate it.

And remember, my operating system is **Linux Mint MATE 32bit.**

Comment: Please describe the way you are trying to update.

Comment: Whatever works. I want to use the command line though.

Comment: What have you already tried? What failed, what error messages do you get?

Comment: I looked it up EVERYWHERE, and whatever I tried, it said something like E: no command found (it said that 5 times, btw).

Answer (score 0):

Check the available update with:

```
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree –status
```

Update :

```
sudo update-pepperflashplugin-nonfree –install
```

**Edit**

To install the plugin run:

```
sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree
```

Comment: It says I have "the most recent", but I don't. Is this for Firefox? I need one for Chromium.

Comment: Of course for chromium

Comment: k. but some of the games I REALLY want to play say "To play (The game I'm trying to play) please install Adobe Flash Player version 11.4.0 or greater."

Comment: The newest version is `11.2` check it [here](https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/)

Comment: for some reason it goes to a 'no_redirect'  page and there is no download button, i guess it loaded the basic HTML view. How can that be?